# How to make Toast to display LogCat text?

Tags: android, logcat, toast, server-response

I have an HttpPost which sends data to a server to be stored on a database. When that data is successfully stored I get a response in my LogCat that says "message has been saved successfully" (this response was defined in my PHP code). I am happy with that, but I am trying to get that same response to be displayed in a Toast. Here is my code:

```
String myBreadfromr, myBreadtor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle myBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
    myBreadfromr = myBasket.getString("keyfromcellr");
    myBreadtor = myBasket.getString("keytocellr");
    new SendData().execute("");
}

public class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute(String f) {
        // called before doInBackground has started
        f = "f";
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create a new HTTP client
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Create a new HTTP Post
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx/androidp2p/process.php");
        try {
            // Add the data
            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from", myBreadfromr));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to", myBreadtor));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "What is your location?"));
            // Encode Post data into valid URL format
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            // Go back to the first page
            Intent back2start = new Intent(RequestLocation.this, StartApp.class);
            startActivity(back2start);
            // Make the HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            // Convert the response into a String
            final HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            // Write the response to a log file
            if (resEntity != null) {
                Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                   public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(RequestLocation.this, resEntity.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
            });
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            uee.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
            cpe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // called when the background task has made any progress
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        // called after doInBackground has finished
    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

What I see in the Toast instead is: "org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@41284b48".

Thanking you in advance for any help in resolving this matter.

Comment: Should you be using ``EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)`` for creating Toast String too instead of ``resEntity.toString``?

Comment: As @harism says. But couldn't you work that out for yourself?

Comment: Thanks. In addition, you must comment out the `Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity))` for the code to work, because `EntityUtils` cannot be called in the same code twice I believe. And like @gpasci said for good programming practice, run the `Toast` in the `onPostExecute` by making this:`String data = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);` in the `doInBackground`, and then using that string "data" in the `Toast`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)` in the Toast to get the same text.

Also no need to call `runOnUiThread`, `doInBackground` must return something, not `null`, and that something will be available `onPostExecute` which already is made to run on the UI thread.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: @harism - When I use EntityUtils.toString(resEntity) in the Toast instead of resEntity.toString(), it asks me to surround with a try and catch, which compiles. However, when I run the code on the emulator, when the Toast is called the emulator crashes.

Comment: If I put the Toast in onPostExecute, an error pops up that says "resEntity cannot be resolved". And also, does doInBackground have to return something if I use AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> instead of AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> ? - @gpasci